# Dynamic array in woocommerce form field (Select field)

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a dynamic array data that needs to send to woocommerce select fields as options. First, I defined the array **$pickup_array** outsied the function. Then, I try to use foreach loop for **$pickup_array** and set the select options, but it does not work, showing:

***syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting ')'***

```
$pickup_array;

//print_r($pickup_array);
stdClass Object
(
    [address] => address1
    ...
    [id] => 000000001
    [type] => pick
)

//var_dump($pickup_array);
{
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#3136 (10) {

    ["address"]=>
    string(38) "address1"
    ...
    ["id"]=>
    string(9) "000000001"
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "pickup"

  }
```

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'pickup_checkout_field');


function pickup_checkout_field( ) {

woocommerce_form_field( 'pickup', array(
    'type' => 'select',
    'required' => 'true',
    'class' => array('pickup-class form-row-wide'),
    'label' =>__('Select address'),
    'options' => array( 
        foreach($pickup_array as $obj){
            "'".$obj->id."'" ."=>". "'".$obj->address."',";
        }
    ),
    $checkout->get_value( 'pickup' ));
}
```

I also try to pass the array directly, but it just showing nothing in the frontend.

```
function pickup_checkout_field( ) {

$result = array();
foreach($pickup_array as $obj){
    $result["$obj->id"] = "$obj->address";
}



woocommerce_form_field( 'pickup', array(
    'type' => 'select',
...
    'options' => $result,
...
);
}
```

I tried apply the variable but found an weird thing,

When I define the array variable and pass it, it is not working, but it works as a static format
//

```
$options = array('000000001' => 'address1');

woocommerce_form_field( 'pickup', array(
...
    'options' => $options,

))
```

But it is normally displayed in following format

```
woocommerce_form_field( 'pickup', array(
...
    'options' => array('000000001' => 'address1'),

))
```

It means I can't use variable to store the dynamic data

Comment: It's weird, it should not be affected. Are you the variable is not overwritten in the process? Change the name and make sure each key is unique.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an array to the options parameter.

You're trying to build an array as PHP code, but you're passing a String instead of an array. But that's not how PHP work.

You need to define an array and add items to it. Then pass it to the options key:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'pickup_checkout_field');

function pickup_checkout_field( ) {
  $options = [];
  foreach($pickup_array as $obj){
    $options[obj->thirdPartyId] = $obj->address;
  }

  woocommerce_form_field( 'pickup', array(
    'type' => 'select',
    'required' => 'true',
    'class' => array('pickup-class form-row-wide'),
    'label' =>__('Select address'),
    'options' => $options,
     $checkout->get_value( 'pickup' )
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Skatox, I tried apply the variable but found an weird thing,

Comment: Can you give me more details to help you solve it and have an answer marked as selected?

Comment: Sure, plz check my edited code